# android Notification doesnt trigger BroadcastReceiver's onReceive

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

Is it possible to have a notification start a broadcast receiver?

I tried this code but it doesnt work.

Notification is created but when I click on it nothing happens.

NOTE: When I change the notificationIntent to point from MyBroadcastReceiver.class to an activity (like MainActivity.class) it works fine.

Notification creation:

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(
        Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int notificationIconId = XXXXXX
    Notification notification = new Notification(
        notificationIconId,
        XXXXXX,
        System.currentTimeMillis()
    );

    CharSequence contentTitle = XXXXXXX
    CharSequence contentText = XXXXXX

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(1,notification);
```

Here is the BroadcastReceiver

```
public static class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   /*
          */

 }
}
```

Inside AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" />
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From your code...

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

When creating a `PendingIntent` targetting a `BroadcastReceiver`, you have to use `getBroadcast(...)` and not `getActivity(...)`.

See [PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

Also, don't create your `Intent` like this...

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
```

That is an explicit `Intent` which targets a specific class (used for starting a specific `Activity` class usually).

Instead create a 'broadcast' `Intent` with an 'action' such as...

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(MyApp.ACTION_DO_SOMETHING);
```

You'll also need to specify a `<intent-filter>` section for the `<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" />` section of your manifest.

Comment: @Abhishek : No problem. First time I worked with notifications, I fell into the same trap with using `getActivity` for a `PendingIntent` when I actually wanted to start a `Service` (which uses `getService`). A lesson well learnt. :)

Comment: @Abhishek you forgot to mention setClass for the notificationIntent `notificationIntent.setClass(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);`

Comment: Please note that the second part of this answer is not really correct. For manifest-registered Receivers, an explicit `Intent` is perfectly fine, and certainly preferred. Indeed, as of API level 26, for apps targeting that version and above, implicit `Intent`s no longer work for Receivers registered in the manifest, [except for a few specific system broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions). You can still set an action on the `Intent`, to discern different broadcasts within the Receiver, but you will not need the `<intent-filter>` on the `<receiver>`.