# Android 'BadTokenException window token android.os.BinderProxy@4250d6d8 is not valid' with foreground service running

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-service, android-alertdialog

Trying to build an android application using kotlin where I am connecting, sending and reading data from a BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) device. I have designed an activity which will show me connection stats and data that is being received from BLE device.And I have a foreground service running to keep the connection with the BLE device alive and listen to the stats.
I have used pending intent to open this activity from my foreground service notification.

Following code shows the method to create notification

```
private fun getServiceNotification(textToShowInNotification: String)
{
        val pendingIntent = Intent(<Static context from application class>,ActivityName::class.java)
        pendingIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        val contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(<static_context_from_application_class>, 0, pendingIntent, 0)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel("DATA_CHANNEL", <Static context from application class>.resources.getString(R.string.app_name),NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
            notificationManager!!.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
        }

        notification = notificationBuilder!!.setOngoing(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setContentText(textToShowInNotification)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .build()
        notificationManager!!.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
}
```

Since I have the use case to open the activity where BLE connections and data receiving is shown. Multiple instances of the activity is created and previous once is not destroyed and because of the same I am unable to get the context of the running activity and due to this I am facing a problem to show alert dialogs in the activity.

Actual Usecase - When the connection with device is established and data is listened from service at that time when I kill the app and open it from foreground service notification, the dialog which has to show up saying that my device is still connected and data is being received is not shown and exceptions occurs when dialog is to be displayed

Following errors/ exceptions occurs when trying to show alert dialogs

```
D/DialogExecption: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
D/DialogExecption: Unable to add window token android.os.BinderProxy@4250d6d8 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

I have used below code to show the dialog

```
private fun showAlertDialog()
{
    val dialogAlertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(<Activity Context>)
    val inflater: LayoutInflater = layoutInflater
    val dialogAlertView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_xml_file,null)
    dialogAlertDialog.setView(dialogAlertView)
    dialogAlertDialog.setCancelable(false)

    val builderAlertDialog : AlertDialog = dialogAlertDialog.create()
    try
    {
        builderAlertDialog.show()
    }
    catch(exception: Exception)
    {
        Log.d("DialogExecption",""+exception.message)
    }
}
```

I have also tried the way

```
if (!this.isFinishing)
{
    builderAlertDialogCycleCancelled.show()
}
```

but this too is not helping. Above code will supress the execption but I don't want to do it instead I want to show the dialog at any cost.

To give a pov I have tried the below in my manifest file to keep a single instance of the activity possible but this is not working out.

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeGeneral">

</activity>
```

I have to use alert dialog in the best possible way and skipping it isn't a choice.
Any help would be great.

**Important Note** - I am using Coroutines with scope Dispatchers.IO in my activity to fetch data from the BLE Device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Observations

> ```
>     notification = notificationBuilder!!.setOngoing(true)
>         .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
>         .setContentText(textToShowInNotification)
>         .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
>         .build()
>     notificationManager!!.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
> ```

Clicking on this notification may not start an `Activity` because `notification` is missing `setSmallIcon` or similar `setIcon` call. To fix it, set some icon as below:

```
     notification = notificationBuilder!!.setOngoing(true)
         .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
         .setContentText(textToShowInNotification)
         .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background) 
         .build()
     notificationManager!!.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
```

> previous activity is not destroyed

That's doubtful because you're using flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` when starting an `Activity`,and that will finish all previous Activities. Otherwise, please show the relevant code.

> When the connection with device is established and data is listened
> from service at that time when I kill the app and open it from
> foreground service notification, the dialog which has to show up
> saying that my device is still connected and data is being received is
> not shown

This sounds quite confusing. It sounds like you're showing it from your `Activity`, but then it's unlikely to fail, especially, if you show it from `onCreate` of your `Activity`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    showAlertDialog()
}
```

> D/DialogExecption: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is
> your activity running? D/DialogExecption: Unable to add window token
> android.os.BinderProxy@4250d6d8 is not valid; is your activity
> running?

The error message is quite clear - you're trying to show a dialog based on an invalid `Context` here `AlertDialog.Builder(<context>)`. For instance, if you use `applicationContext` or a `Service` `context` there, it will fail with such exception.

You claim to start your dialog with an `Activity` context as below:

```
...
val dialogAlertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(<Activity Context>)
...
```

However, it's not clear from your code from where `showAlertDialog()` is called, and the context object is not shown either. So, I created a sample project to test the described behaviour.

## Suggestion

### Preparation

I tried reproducing the issue by building a minimalistic project based on the information that you provided in your question. *Please note that I'm not using any BLE functionality for this example, even though **Bluetooth** is used as a prefix for each component*.

I created a foreground service `BluetoothDeviceService` responsible for starting an `Activity`, when a notification is clicked.

#### BluetoothDeviceService.kt

```
class BluetoothDeviceService: Service() {
    private val SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 123
    private val SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "channel_01"

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                "Bluetooth service",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
            val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)

            val pendingIntent = Intent()
            pendingIntent.setClass(this,BluetoothDeviceActivity::class.java)
            pendingIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            val contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                pendingIntent, 0)

            val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setContentText("Bluetooth service running...")
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .build()
            startForeground(SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
        }
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        return START_STICKY
    }
}
```

I created a `MainActivity` that had to start the foreground service.

#### MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val startServiceIntent = Intent(this, BluetoothDeviceService::class.java)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForegroundService(startServiceIntent)
        } else {
            startService(startServiceIntent)
        }
        finish()
    }
}
```

**Please note that the `Service` could also be started by `BroadcastReceiver`, and that would be more appropriate, but I used the `Activity` for simplicity.**

Also, I introduced a `BluetoothDeviceActivity` that was started by the service with help of `PendingIntent`:

#### BluetoothDeviceActivity.kt

```
class BluetoothDeviceActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        showAlertDialog()
    }
}

private fun showAlertDialog() {
    val dialogAlertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setMessage("This is a test")
        .setTitle("Information")
        .create()

    dialogAlertDialog.show()
}
```

Just in case, I also put my manifest.

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.stackoverflowquestion2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.StackOverflowQuestion2"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.StackOverflowQuestion2.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".BluetoothDeviceActivity"/>

        <service android:name=".BluetoothDeviceService"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

### Result

This worked as expected without any problems.

## Further suggestion

One other idea - you could convert your `AlertDialog` to `Activity` and use it as a `Dialog`. For this, you need to do 2 things:

1. Create a new `Àctivity` as below:

   ```
   class AlertDialogActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
       override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

           val dialogAlertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setMessage("This is a test")
               .setTitle("Information")
               .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, which -> finish() }
               .create()

           dialogAlertDialog.show()
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add it to your manifest and set its theme as `Dialog`:

   ```
   <activity android:name=".AlertDialogActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"/>
   ```
3. Then, create a method in your `Service`, and use it any time it's needed:

   ```
   private fun showAlertDialog() {
       val intent = Intent(applicationContext, AlertDialogActivity::class.java)
       intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
       applicationContext.startActivity(intent)
   }
   ```

### Result

That's what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create class that extends [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/BroadcastReceiver) class.

Your notification will trigger BroadcastReceiver's onReceive method.

See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10941160/9972209) how to do it

one [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17906078/9972209) and [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844031/alertdialog-from-within-broadcastreceiver-can-it-be-done)

```
onReceive(context: Context!,  intent: Intent!)
```

Based on action of your intent you will call method that shows AlertDialog in corresponding context

Answer (score -1):

You should use ViewModel. Create a MainViewModel for your activity, in this ViewModel you create a MutableLiveData: isShowDialog. When you want to show a dialog, you will call a method of MainViewModel for updating the value of isShowDialog variable (true). In MainActivity, you will observer isShowDialog variable, if it is true, you call the method to show a dialog. ViewModel will make sure that the method for showing a dialog will be called when your activity is ready.

Answer (score -1):

What is stopping you from moving away from `AlertDialog` to just `Dialog` which can be called with application context rather than with activity one or `DialogFragment` that doesn't require context at all - only `fragmentManager`(still may cause corner cases problems)? The application context is always the same and if your application is active it is always there. The only drawback is that you may have to customize the UI of your dialog a bit more.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
dialog.show();
```

or

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new BleDialogFragment();
newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "bleStuff");
```